# Is there a formula to activate the hyperlinks in excel using a thousands of rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hello guys I just want to ask if there's a formula to activate hyperlinks in excel. Let's say I have 10,000 rows in column D all the rows consists of URL. I know how to activate it using F2 command but I have 10,000 rows. How can I do that? Thanks.

This is the example link I have

https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=14.187654492607,121.125096715986

Answer (score 0):

In E1, enter:

**=HYPERLINK(D1,D1)**  and copy down.

With VBA you could also create a macro that would active them "in place".